# Cordova 2.xx Plugin Procedure

Tags: android, cordova, sequence, procedure

I don't quite understand the cordova plugin procedure.
I found out that it works through the Cordova Webview, but I don't know which
functions and classes are necessary.

It would be great if someone had the time to explain it, a sequencediagramm would be the best for understanding.

greetings, Kurt

Comment: What do you mean by plugin procedure? Each plugin has its specific way to be integrated to your phonegap project.

Comment: the way from the JavaScript exec to the cordovaplugin class thru the webview.

Comment: Does the official guide doesn't give enough info. ? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

Comment: yeah, the official guide is good, but i want to know wath's going in in the Background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you to understand more:

> ### [Using WebViews](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/09/using-webviews.html)
>
> A WebView uses the same rendering and JavaScript engine as the browser, but it runs under the control of your application. The WebView can be full screen or you can mix it with other Views. The content for your WebView can come from anywhere. The WebView can download content from the web, or it can come from local files stored in your assets directory. The content can even be dynamically generated by your application code.

and

> ### [Android WebView, Javascript and CSS](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/android-webview-javascript-and-css.html)
>
> I have come across some situations where I had to use a WebView to display some HTML content. Displaying HTML content is pretty straight-forward. But when it comes to controlling the web view, it gets a little complex. Things like showing alerts, manipulating divs and controlling the activity (closing/finishing). This example shows a few techniques that will get you going with Javascript and CSS with WebView.

Comment: thanks, helped a lot. Is this the way cordova works with the webview?

Comment: Yes. Phonegap use the native webview, and create a bridge so that the plugins which are most are written in native language can communicate with javascript in the webview.